# Shrink an entire view together on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, view, scrollview

I have a scrollview, with multiple views inside.
I want one of the Views to scroll together ie on scroll either be shown entirely, or hidden completely (the view shouldnt be seen partially)
How can this be done in react native?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://snack.expo.io/6CSRNageW) example can help you